# What is the best way to save iPhone battery?

Tags: iphone, battery, performance

Since I've moved to iPhone 4 from a 3Gs, my battery drops down extremely fast. If i use it for 20 minutes at the beginning of the day it goes from 100% to 60% and by 3PM with normal use it's at 20%.
What are the best settings to have as little battery drain while the screen is sleeping while keeping the internet and cellular connections active?

Comment: While there are lots of ways to save battery life, you'd just be better off with a new battery. Try ifixit.com.

Comment: What does "save battery" mean to you? Why not turn everything off? Also, consider researching Apple's article on extending the time between charges and explain how it does or doesn't help in your situation.

Comment: @bmike well, if you read my question, you should understand what "saving battery" means :) I used to be able to spend a whole day with one charge on the 3GS, and not the 4 - which one would believe is more advanced - lasts a mere 6 hours outside of the house. One approach is to turn 3G and Cellular data off, but that shuts off the internet connection. I guess my question is: "what settings will deplete the battery the least while maintaining internet connection and cellular data active?" Say how often does an app like Facebook for example fetches notifications on the server? Can I change this?

Comment: @fabriced Have a look at [help] on how to edit the post which kicks it into review for releasing the temporary hold. Comments get cleared often, so putting critical information to clarify the question there isn't the best place. Does that work for you?

Comment: I edited it now it's different

Answer (score 1):

To keep it simple:

- Limit the time spent connected to the Internet
- Kill open apps when you don't need them
- Disable push notifications for apps that don't need immediate response.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend restoring the device once and not installing any app for a day to two to recalibrate the battery and diagnose any battery related issues. After that follow the steps given by @Ebe. I normally install an app and check if it decimates my battery before installing another one.